# Counting how many rows satisfy a condition for each id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing multiple features. In the same dataset the features are grouped by 'id' column from 1 to 10. I need to count **the number of rows of 'vout' which are > 0.2** for **each group id** and save it for every single id.

```
    id    freq    zr         zi           z        vout    
1   1   4641.60 0.010534    -0.002541   0.010687    0.63490
2   1   2154.40 0.010787    -0.000516   0.010786    0.63471
3   1   1000.00 0.011431    0.000674    0.011366    0.63451
4   1   464.16  0.012167    0.001527    0.012232    0.63432
```

the result must be something like this:

```
id 1 -> numbRows = 1304
id 2 -> numbRows = 3234
...
id 10 ->numbRows = 223
```

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first filter, then group by the `id`, and finally calculate the number of rows:

```
df[df['vout'] > 0.2].groupby('id')['vout'].count()
```

Comment: Top! Awesome, but I get the results repeatly for each feature:
``` 
freq Zreal Zimag Z Vout
id     
1 878 878 878 878 878
2 694 694 694 694 694
3 727 727 727 727 727
4 759 759 759 759 759
5 881 881 881 881 881
6 882 882 882 882 882
7 833 833 833 833 833
8 884 884 884 884 884
9 819 819 819 819 819
10 706 706 706 706 706
```

Comment: @Nikos90: ah, you can select a single column then, so adding a `['vout']` for example.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you very much.